# Running app Node.js on webhosting - not local -

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I run part of my Node app in my web hosting? I did the core of the web application in PHP, but some part was done in Node.js. From PHP, I call some service that was done in Node.js.

I uploaded my website to my cloud server. It is a service that I bought in a company specialized in selling domains and webhosting. I installed node using terminal access that they provide, but I can't understand what to do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pm2 to start and manage apps.
For reference use this doc.
https://in.godaddy.com/help/set-up-nodejs-application-for-production-ubuntu-17352

Comment: i am going to read this information :)  Thank you very much !

Comment: It's quite a straight forward approach. If it serves the purpose make sure to accept the answer and upvote.

Comment: sorry i try to upvote and can't there is a message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."   when i have 15 reputation i will come back and upvote :)